# How can I get media keys working on my Dell Vostro 2520?

Tags: dell, function-keys

Some of combinations with <kbd>Fn</kbd> on my Dell Vostro 2520 don't seem to work.

- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (rewind back)
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (play/stop)
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (rewind forward)

I think that these keys need to be set up system-wide. I looked *settings manager* → *window manager* → *keyboard* and some other places. Yet I fail to find where to set up these keys.

Could you tell me where to set thease keys up or a player that will understand them straight away? I'm using [Aqualung [image: Install aqualung]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aqualung) currently.

**Update 1**
I've tried media keys in  [banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee). Don't work there too.
And no dell provided drivers.

**Update 2**
But in [parole](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/parole) media keys work! hm... now i need to pick up mp3 player

Comment: Dell sells this device with Ubuntu 11.10 pre-installed as well and the Ubuntu certification programme for the [Vostro 2520](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10558/) states it is only certified with this preinstalled image. Please check the Dell support page for any hints on this - they may have a fix/package/article about this for Ubuntu. These media keys should be working out of the box with regular media players. Can you check this with the Ubuntu default player?

Comment: As of update 2 - would there be any suggestions about mp3 players ?